# Need web editor with some extra functions

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg

I'm searching for WYSIWYG editor, which has some built-in (or maybe plug-in) extra functions such as: drawing math graphics, writing math formulas... etc. Found MathJAX but as far as I know, mathjax requires TeX code input to convert it into graphics, and there is no plug-in for famous open-source web editors (like CKeditor...)

Any suggestions for this purpose?

Comment: I think that there are one or two plugins to use math formulas with CKEditor, but I guess that you have already checked them. It would be useful for other people to explain why they don't fit your needs.

Comment: which plugins, please tell me

Comment: These ones for example: http://www.google.com/search?q=ckeditor+mathml+plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/ckeditor/install.php